# Get error "Too many authentication failures" by connecting to AWS EC2 through vnc viewer

Tags: amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have set up an environment with AWS EC2 based on ubuntu 14.04 and configure `vncserver` under it. After everything is done, I am able to connect the EC2 `instance` with VNC viewer and see the desktop. However, after a period of time idle on `vncviewer`, the connection is disconnected and I have error

> "Too many authentication failures"

After I restart the `vncserver` by going through ssh to EC2, I am able to use `vncviewer` to connect to the instance again. Any solution for me to not having the error and connection is not disconnected?

[image]

Comment: have you configured security groups? or are you being attacked from the world on a wide open port? _voting to close as off topic_

Comment: hi, i add the port into configured security groups in aws EC2 configuration. and no, I do think i am being attached from the world

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same scenario. For me this happened because, multiple sessions of `vncserver` was running on my Server. Do the following steps...

**Step 1: See the multiple VNC sessions running on your server.**

You will see multiple process IDs running. (If not, still proceed to the next steps)

```
$ pgrep vnc

72063
119177
```

This is because you have run `vncserver` command multiple times on the server.

**Step 2: Kill all processes from step 1**

```
$ kill 72063
$ kill 119177
```

**Step 3: Restart the VNC session**

```
$ vncserver
```

**Step 4: Verify whether it is working.**

```
$ nc 104.197.91.140 5901
// alternatively you can use telnet
$ telnet 104.197.91.140 5901

// the response should like this
RFB 003.008
```

- Simply try loading the VNC viewer session again

Answer (score -1):

You might try these commands:

```
# echo $DISPLAY
# ps -aef | grep sesman
# netstat -natp | grep vnc
```

If memory serves, if you get to more than ten no-longer-established vnc sessions, some VNC clients no longer allow additional connections. In this case, you need to kill the vnc processes that no longer have the established status.